# webpack not generating bundle.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, bundle, webpack-dev-server

I am making a web app use react and php and i am using webpack for es6 to js so i generated files but i have a problem about webpack output bundle.js file.

> this is my webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.jsx'
  ],
  output: {
    path: '/dist',
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['env', 'react']
        }
      }
    }, {
      test: /(\.css|.scss)$/,
      use: [{
        loader: "style-loader"
      }, {
        loader: "css-loader"
      }, {
        loader: "sass-loader"
      }]
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

> this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback --progress --colors --config ./webpack.config.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.18",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.1.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "reactstrap": "^5.0.0-beta"
  }
}
```

why webpack generate and give me a bundle.js into the dist folder ? only saves it to the memory and show it on the localhost. i want use this react app with php but i can not handle to bundle.js.
Where is the problem and why the webpack did not generate the js file.
please help me

Comment: this is because you are running webpack-dev-server. run webpack. In scripts add `"build": "webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback --progress --colors --config ./webpack.config.js"` as second line. Seperate both by a `,`

Comment: what sould i write in the script exactly ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your webpack configuration output filed got problem.

import `const path = require('path')` first in webpack.config.js and change `output` filed as below:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
}
```

And add following script into your package.json in `script` filed

`"build": "webpack -p --progress"`

Run `npm run build`

Comment: I would try this one. Put the const path statement at the top of your webpack config file, then change the output like yue says. See what happens.

Comment: Glad that I can help

Comment: This working for me as it's generating a bundle, but now it is not watching the files and not opening with the port `localhost:8080`

Comment: Watching files is not related to this config. It is related to https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour for webpack dev server. If you wish to generate the output on disk, you need to run `webpack`, e.g:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback ...",
  "build": "webpack"
}
```

then run `npm build`. For production, you should also set `NODE_ENV=production`, for example using [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env):

```
"build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack"
```

Comment: not any error message. 
i got only this

Version: webpack 3.10.0
Time: 3784ms
           Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
./dist/bundle.js  1.49 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
  [38] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
  [44] multi ./src/index.jsx 28 bytes {0} [built]
  [45] ./src/index.jsx 604 bytes {0} [built]
    + 122 hidden modules

Comment: and a `./dist/bundle.js` file outputted?

Comment: Your config is incorrect for the output settings - see the example at https://webpack.js.org/configuration/. i.e. it states 'output.path' must be an absolute path